# Did technology progress at all by 138 ABY

Tags: star-wars

I've been reading the Star Wars Legacy Prisoner of the Floating World comics and I'm trying to see if technology is slightly better by 138 ABY. I can't tell, can anyone help me?

Here's what I've observed:

- Ships look the same
- Tractor beam is visible red (could be an artists aesthetic choice)
- Blaster bolts are yellow (again could be an aesthetic choice)
- old SD unit, considered old (AG-37 mentioned he's been around for a long time, hinting the AG series is old)
  comm droid- could be just a model
- Shifala speeder bikes- look very similar to the ones in ROTJ
- Communications Array- that might be a technological advancement
- Ice Mining Platform- never saw that before
- Energy binders- might be an advancement, along with Sith helmet. Could be Krayt development

Comment: What technology are you looking to advance?  There is quite a bit of ship development, Lando had some gain in mining, and with the defeat of the YV there is quite a bit of advances in bioengineering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By and large, technology hasn't really improved in the Star Wars universe for a LONG time.

The core technologies used all show signs of hitting their plateaus.  Most major developments are those of miniaturization, scale, or application.  The Death Star, for example, didn't incorporate any new technologies, it just scaled up existing weapons to a ludicrous size.  The only major hardships it faced were engineering - it had to improve power flow, vent waste heat, etc in bigger and better ways.  It was also a logistical nightmare - building it required moving a lot of mass, hiring a lot of workers, etc.

To demonstrate my point, consider the novel *Darksaber*.  In this novel, a Hutt gets his grubby mitts on the plans for the Death Star (just the blueprints).  He is able, within a very short timeframe, to build a stripped-down version.  It eliminated most of the hemispheres, keeping only the core functions.  It's implied that his construction of the superstructure was completed quickly, though it was flawed due to epic levels of ADHD on the part of his construction crews.

Consider what that means: Everything you need to build a Death Star, every technology, is available to a Hutt 'crime lord' so incompetent he could be played like a fiddle by Prince Xizor.  Durga the Hutt was so cheap that his knockoff Death Star had less quality control than a made-in-taiwan knockoff of this year's popular Christmas toy.  There's absolutely NO chance that he spent billions of credits recreating lost technologies - he was able to pick up everything he needed through his black market connections.

This is symptomatic of a technological society which has ceased innovating.  The Old Republic lasted for 'a thousand generations' and was a stable political body of the style which can only come from disparate peoples who have long been in contact coming together under a common banner.  New technologies tend to buck the system, change drastically how people live and work.  It's unlikely that the Republic could have lasted that long if there were many significant technological changes.

Therefore, outside of radical new bioengineering technologies introduced by the Vong, there's no reason to expect that technology would change significantly within such a (relatively) short timeframe.

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Wow. A great answer supported by canon (of some level). +1

Comment: It honestly sort of pains me to recall all of that information about Darksaber - it was a terrible book and killed one of my favorite characters.